# Subselect working on dev machine, but not live, with the same database, and both running mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql

This query is working perfectly on my dev machine, a PC with mysql 5.1.53

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * 
 FROM   posts P1
 WHERE  user_id IN (2,1000001) AND NOT track_id = 34 AND
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts P2 
            WHERE P2.user_id = P1.user_id AND P2.id > P1.id AND P2.track_id <> 34)
         <= 1
 GROUP BY 
        track_id 
 ORDER BY 
        id desc LIMIT 5
```

when i run the very same piece of code in the same database on my live server (debian, mysql 5.1.39), i get this error:

```
Unknown column 'P1.user_id' in 'where clause':
```

How could this be? Any ideas?

Result of `show create table posts` on the server

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`track_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
`tag_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`comment` tinytext,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`commentcount` tinyint(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `track_id` (`track_id`),
KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`),
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=484 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: I tend to believe what the error message says: Your `Posts` table in your live server does not have a column called user_id.

Comment: Check case as well -- is the table column defined as user_id or User_id?

Comment: It does have that column. The column is called "user_id" (all lower case) both here and on the server.

Comment: How about the case of the table? Is it posts or Posts?

Comment: Update the question with the results of `show create table posts` on your live server, just to be sure. Nothing in your query looks blatantly wrong, although it's good practice to always alias all field references, just for clarity.

Comment: On linux MySQL can be case sensitive, on windows it never is. This might be the problem.

Comment: Here's a link that might help you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html.  You can also try the query I gave you in the answer that query came from, it pretty much does the same thing.

Comment: Just updated the question as you said, @DougKress.

Comment: You were absolutely right, Dante617 and Johan. It was a matter of case sensitivity. The problem was that I gave posts the alias "p1" and then went on to use "P1". Duh.

Comment: Is it customary to delete questions with no answer I can accept?

Comment: @Jocke this is something you have to search for / ask for on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a lot of comments suggested, it was an issue with case sensitivity. In the SQL query on the server, the alias of posts was set to "p1", but the subselect was looking for "P1". Mistake.